# Why does ice fall from the top of the ice tray first?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

I haven't found an answer for this anywhere, so hopefully this community can help.  It's not important at all that I know this but I'm curious.

If you take a plastic tray of ice from the freezer and twist it to loosen all the cubes, then you tip it up on a long end, the cubes at the top of the tilted tray tend to fall out first. Since the angle of all the cubes should be the same, I'm assuming that some differential in force is at work. Presumably, the force of gravity would be very slightly stronger on the lower cubes, so that doesn't seem to account for it.

So what's going on here?

Comment: A few questions - does this happen every single time? If not, what percentage of the time? I have a built-in icemaker, so I can't easily test this. Are you sure the angle is the same for your tray? Perhaps the tray is warped? Are you holding the top of the ice cube tray with your hand? Does it still happen if you use tongs, or hold it from the middle?

Comment: When you tip it up, the cubes at the top of the tray are accelerated faster (farther from the axis of rotation.)  This breaks more of the little tiny connections between the ice and the plastic?

Comment: Perhaps the top of the tray warms more quickly than the lower part, which is near the table top and semi-shielded from air circulation.  Cold air from the ice and tray would tend to form a layer at the table top, near the lower part of the tray.

Comment: I'm thinking that Adam is onto something with the acceleration. The tray is flat and it happens with various types of trays. I tried tipping more slowly and the cubes seemed to come out randomly across the whole try. Tipping faster seems to make the top cubes more likely to fall first.

Comment: In a frost-free fridge the freezer compartment is colder at the rear. This could affect the flexibility of the plastic or how the ice sticks to it. Was one end closer to the rear? Do you habitually use the same hand to pull out the tray and to hold the upper end when tilting?

Answer (score 1):

The velocity of this "tipping" increases Linearily with radius. But the [kinetic energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_energy) grows exponentially with velocity. This means that at the top, the ice cubes have 4 x more kinetic energy, than in the half of the tip radius. The result is obvious.